# mysql - how to copy date when copying table

Tags: mysql, date, copy

I need to copy a MySQL table which contains a date field of timestamp type defaulted to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
The query below works fine for all the data but does not copy the date field, which I need to carry over.

```
 insert into table1 select * from table2 order by record-Id.
```

Thanks in advance.